# How to add the code block on Xcode10?

Tags: xcode10, ios12

I can't drag code to Library on Xcode10

[image: Library]

Comment: Please describe more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow are the steps to add custom code snippet

Step1 - Select your code snippet and right click. Then select 'create Code snippet'

Step2 - Give your title for the snippet and save.

[image]

[image]

Comment: does this solution help?

Comment: ![picture](https://i.loli.net/2018/08/25/5b816bfd3fbcc.jpg)I touch it,but there are an error,probably because I was forbidden to ask questions.

Comment: I'm very sorry,I just used the platform,so I don't konw how to click on the tick mark.I try to ![touch this](https://i.loli.net/2018/08/26/5b82257b285b7.jpg) and find out that this is for a complaint.